# How to get distinct urls for published google sheets in the same spreadsheet

Tags: web-applications, google-sheets

I have one Google Sheet File with several sheets in it, those sheets are used for display purpose in a company through few TVs. Each TVmust display one of the sheet. Since the TVs are connected to the internet, I simply published the google sheet on the web and with a browser on the TVs I go to the url Google gave me while publishing. 
The url is the same for all the sheets in my spreadsheet, so I have to manually chose the sheet browsing the url. The problem is there are often automatic refreshs, so since the url is unique, after a refresh I always go backs to the first sheet so the TV doesn't display anymore the sheet it was supposed to be.
Is there anyway, through the url, to indicates which sheet in the spreadsheet we want to display?

Comment: This doesn't look as a programming question. Consider to ask it on [webapps.se].

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheet url can point to a specific sheet within the spreadsheet. Look at the URL: when you are viewing the first sheet, the url ends with: gid=0; when you change the view to another sheet, the url will change and show that sheet number (for instance: gid=1818144906).

Try to modify the given URL for the TV set to include the gid number; that should force the browser to load directly your desired sheet.

I hope that work.

Comment: Hi Marcos, indead there is a gid= in the url of the google sheet itself, but there is not in the webview url Google gives you after publishing

Comment: Hi again. I don´t know if this workaround is possible according to your needs, but let´s see: Another option is to create different spreadsheet for each sheet in the original spreadsheet. Open the first spreadsheet, reflect the content of the first original sheet using =IMPORTRANGE and publish that spreadsheet on the web (not the original). Give the TV that url. If you repeat this process for each sheet, when finished, you can control the contents of each sheet from the original spreadsheet, and the others (the published) will auto-update as you make changes. Is this an option?